# Foreign Key that refers two tables

Tags: oracle, database-design, foreign-keys

I have read other answers on SO and other sites but can not find a solution or may be I am failing to understand.

Here is the problem:

I have these 3 tables in my database

```
MOVIE (Primary Key movie_id)   
(movie_id, movie_name, release_date, running_time, rating, ranking genre_id) 

PEOPLE(Primary Key people_id)   
(people_id, title, family_name, given_name, gender, date_of_birth)

AWARD(Primary Key award_id)    
(award_id, organization_id, title, year, winner)
```

Now the problem is the `winner` attribute of Award table.
According to problem statement an award can be awarded to either a movie or a person.

Therefore from what I understand the `winner` attribute of `AWARD` table should be a `FOREIGN KEY` to `PRIMARY KEY`s of either the `MOVIE/PERSON` table.

Other solutions that I read suggest making a super type for tables but here I do not have any similarity between a Movie and a Person (No common super class). Any suggestion on how to proceed in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWARD can be a super type for PERSON_AWARD and MOVIE_AWARD, since awards are of (at least) two types. (A person can't win 'Best Picture').  So PERSON_AWARD is (award_id, winner) where winner is a foreign key of PEOPLE. MOVIE_AWARD is (award_id, winner) where winner is a foreign key of MOVIE.

Comment: Perfect. Makes Sense. **** So stupid of me.. Thanks Mike. Cheers!!